# Fluid like movement to the items in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to implement a graph nodes something similar to the graph observed in http://audiomap.tuneglue.net/. (To get graph here Enter some text (ex: asd) in the search box. You will get a relationship graph.)

I could build the graph with a set of nodes and i can move them around. But the issue is I want to make fluid movement to other node while a node is dragged. I tried Expression Blend FluidMoveBehaviour. But it didn't fit perfectly like what i wanted.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="SpicyNodes.MainWindow" Name="MainWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SpicyNodes.ViewModels"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpicyNodes"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:GraphItemDataTemplateSelector x:Key="graphItemDataTemplateSelector" ></local:GraphItemDataTemplateSelector>



    <CompositeCollection x:Key="Col">
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Connectors,Source={x:Reference MainWindow1}}"/>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Nodes,Source={x:Reference MainWindow1}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="personTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Person}">
    <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_Drag" DragCompleted="thumb_DragCompleted" DragStarted="thumb_DragStarted" Name="thumb"
                       >


            <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Canvas Margin="-10,-10,10,10">
                        <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="#696969" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#353520"
                                         x:Name="Ellipse">
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Canvas.Top="-20" Canvas.Left="-40" Width="100" FontFamily="Cambria" FontSize="12"
                                           TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           />

                    </Canvas>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>


                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

            </Thumb.Template>




        </Thumb>


    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="connectorTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Connector}">
        <StackPanel>
        <Line Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2"
                        X1="{Binding StartNode.X}" Y1="{Binding StartNode.Y}"
                        X2="{Binding EndNode.X}" Y2="{Binding EndNode.Y}" x:Name="Line">           
        </Line>
        </StackPanel>            
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource graphItemDataTemplateSelector}" 
        Name="items" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Col}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="PanelTemplate">
                <Canvas Name="canvas1" >
                    <!--<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:FluidMoveSetTagBehavior Tag="Element" AppliesTo="Children"/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>-->
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ItemsControl>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Height="30" Width="50">Add</Button>

</Grid>
```

And MainWindow.cs file contains:

```
void _CreateObjectOnCanvas(string Name, double X, double Y)
{
  Person node2 = new Person(Name, "", "");

  node2.Position = new Point(150, 120);

  node2.X = X;

  node2.Y = Y;

  viewModel.Nodes.Add(node2);

  Connector c = new Connector();

  c.StartNode = viewModel.Nodes[0];

  c.EndNode = node2;

  viewModel.Connectors.Add(c);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Random rand = new Random();

  var Angle = rand.Next(0, 360);

  Angle = (Angle * 7) % 360;

  var X = viewModel.Nodes[0].X + 100 * Math.Sin(Angle);

  var Y = viewModel.Nodes[0].Y + 100 * Math.Cos(Angle);

  if (!_CheckForOverlap(X, Y))
  {
    var Person = viewModel.CreatePerson(GIndex++);

    _CreateObjectOnCanvas(Person.Name, X, Y);
  }
}
```

Person class contains the following:

```
double x;
public override double X
{ get { return x; }

  set
  {
    x = value;

    OnPropertyChanged("X");
  }
}


double y;
public override double Y
{
  get { return y; }

  set
  {
    y = value;

    OnPropertyChanged("Y");
  }
}

public string Name { get; set; }

public string Occupation { get; set; }

public string ContactInfo { get; set; }

public System.Windows.Point Position { get; set; }

public Person(string name, string occupation, string contact)
{
  this.Name = name;

  this.Occupation = occupation;

  this.ContactInfo = contact;
}
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated as i spent almost 2 days working on this.

Thank you.